# How to make the button and textbox in orginal look when Enabled is false

Tags: c#, winforms

When I make C# WinForms button and textbox enabled = false color and design get gray so I need any trick or code that make textbox looks Enabled true while its  Enabled = false.

Comment: To make a C# textbox look like it is enabled when it is actually disabled, you can set its BackColor property to the desired color, or set its ReadOnly property to true and set its BackColor to the desired color. #have you tried this?

Comment: Please indicate the UI platform that applies to this question by adding a tag. Is it WinForms? WPF?

Comment: ReadOnly good answer but the pointer enter the textbox so in text boxes I do not want the pointer to appear

Comment: @IVSoftware sorry . its WinForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `TextBox`, one way to achieve this objective is to intercept the `WM_PAINT` message and inspect the `Enabled` property. If it's false, use [TextBoxRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxrenderer) class to draw the text box as if it were enabled.

Try swapping out the instances of `TextBox` in your designer file with this custom version:

```
class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    const int WM_PAINT = 0x000F;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg.Equals(WM_PAINT) && !Enabled)
        {
            paintDisabled();
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    private void paintDisabled()
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
        {
            TextBoxRenderer.DrawTextBox(
                graphics, 
                Bounds,
                System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.TextBoxState.Normal
            );
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**Button**

In this case, the `ButtonRendererClass` is used instead.

```
class ButtonEx : Button
{
    const int WM_PAINT = 0x000F;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg.Equals(WM_PAINT) && !Enabled)
        {
            paintDisabled();
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    private void paintDisabled()
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
        {
            ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(
                graphics,
                Bounds,
                System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.PushButtonState.Normal
           );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Coo thank you for your reply , but the textbox now with your code accept only one letter or number and for more input letters you have to click again on it to complete writing,

Comment: Could you please try and [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/disabled-textbox-appears-enabled.git) the code I used to test this answer and see whether you observe the issue you describe? There's nothing about this painting scheme that "should" really have any effect like that, but this would be a way to know for sure.

Comment: Another thought: If you have an event handler for the `TextChanged` event or anything like that for your text box, can you please add that handler code to your post? Thx!

Comment: great thank you dear , one more thing if the controller does not contain formatting Enabled property how I can add it ? in example I am using Syncfuion ui and I want to apply this code for group box.

Comment: Happy to help! So, if I understand your comment, aren't you still using the Forms designer to add buttons and textboxes to the Syncfusion UI? If so, then the recommendation stays the same. Wherever you have a `TextBox` swap out for `TextBoxEx` , and `Button` for `ButtonEx` and it seems as though that should work.

Comment: thank for your help, I am using textbox and buttons but still need same code for Syncfusion group box if you can please help.

Comment: I want to (and certainly _can_) help you with Syncfusion group box but that's a new question! If this answer has solved `button` and `textbox` that you asked about please consider clicking '✔' to mark it as an acceptable answer. Then make a new post, something like **Draw Syncfusion group box with normal appearance when disabled.** Add [tags] for **winforms** and **syncfusion**. Add an _image_ of your groupbox. Show the _code_ from the designer where the group box is declared so that we can determine the exact Syncfusion control and reproduce the issue. Thx!